# qualifying sample similarity / difference using population standard deviation

Tags: group-differences

I have a set of students with mean height of 100cm with standard deviation of 10cm. I want to be able to qualify a student based on his/her height relative to the mean height for the group. Would it be possible to look at the deviation of a student's height from the mean height for the group in terms of number of standard deviations and say a certain students height is different, very different from the height of the group - like 1 standard deviation or 2 standard deviations or so - are there typical measures for this ? The distribution is not necessarily `normal`.

Answer (score 0):

- Short answer: Typically if it's over 2 standard deviations, it's considered "different."
- Longer answer: If you approximate the distribution of heights as normal, you can look up the proportion of individuals that fall outside a given number of standard deviations from the mean. For instance, roughly only 5% of students will be over 2 standard deviations away. This lets you quantify just how "extreme" such heights are, and is the basis of the "2 standard deviations" rule of thumb. (Section 3.1.5 of [OpenIntro Statistics](https://www.openintro.org/stat/textbook.php?stat_book=os), Page 136).

Comment: could you please add references

Comment: Sure, I added a text for the first two answers. I deleted my "longer answer" since it doesn't seem as relevant upon re-reading your question.

Comment: I looked at section 3.1.5 which has title `68-95-99.7 rule` - not able to find the reference where it says 2 sds is the right range to consider the sample to be different.

Comment: This is because what is "different" is ultimately subjective. Do you think a 95th percentile is "different?" Or would you require a 99th percentile.